# Transfer money from a bank account to a bitcoin wallet

Tags: money-transfer

How do I transfer or pay money from a bank account into a bitcoin wallet address? Please assist

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer dollars from a bank account directly into a bitcoin wallet.

You’ll need to sign up with a bitcoin exchange service, there are many in existence. Once you have an account with one of them, you can transfer dollars to the exchange’s bank account, and then your user account will be credite. Next you will be able to purchase bitcoins at the current market rate through the exchange.

After that, you can withdraw your bitcoins to a bitcoin wallet you control.

There are other ways to purchase bitcoins too, but I think exchange services are perhaps the most commonly used